# How to handle TSLint Errors in my typescript example

Tags: angularjs, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I have the following angularjs factory examples written in Typescript but am receiving three TSLint errors:

Line 3: expected call-signature: 'FirebaseFactory' to have a typedef
Line 8: expected call-signature: 'AuthFactory' to have a typedef
Line 9: expected call-signature to have a typedef

While I know it is still valid Typescript, I would prefer to ensure that all type checking advantages that TS includes are maintained.

```
module app.services {

    export function FirebaseFactory () {
        return new Firebase('https://sample.firebaseio.com');
    }

    angular.module('app.services').factory('firebaseFactory', FirebaseFactory);

    export function AuthFactory (DB: Firebase, $firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuthService) {
        return function () {
            return $firebaseAuth(DB);
        };
    }

    AuthFactory.$inject = ['firebaseFactory', '$firebaseAuth'];

    angular.module('app.services').factory('authFactory', AuthFactory);
}
```

Is there a way to create interfaces so that I only export the interfaces instead of the functions?  I have done this before with other services that are implemented as classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/palantir/tslint#supported-rules says:

> "call-signature" checks return type of functions

With this rule (I personally prefer to disable it) you should declare types:

```
export function AuthFactory (...): () => AngularFireAuth
```

Regardless of whether you declare type explicetly or not, or even declare interface:

```
export var AuthFactory: { (): AngularFireAuth; } = function (...)
```

outwardly your module looks the same.